# Assembly 8086 most occurring consonant in the string

Tags: algorithm, assembly, x86-16

I'm new in assembly and i have to do this thing, to find most occurring consonant in the string and write the number how many times it has occurred, but I don't know how. Can you help me please with some algorithm on how to do it ? I'm not asking you to make code for me (but i wish i could :D ), only help with algorithm, because I really don't know how should I proceed, thank you very much !

This is how should it look like

```
in: this is test
out: 03


in: abcd egfh ijkmn bbb ccc
out: 04

in: Hey horse how you doin
out: 03

in: THIS is IS is IT
out: 04
```

Answer (score 2):

Histogram alphabetic characters and find the max bin.  Force chars to lowercase with `or al, 0x20` if you want to treat `T` and `t` as the same character.

Filter out vowels somehow, most efficient would be just by skipping or zeroing those bins at the end instead of checking each input char.